# Main file specified in data-main of requireJS is called twice in Chrome (Version 44.0.2403.157 (64-bit))

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, backbone.js, requirejs

I am developing an app using BackboneJS and requireJS, today suddenly I started seeing an error in chrome console.

```
Uncaught Error: Backbone.history has already been started
```

I checked if I've accidentally started the backbone history twice but that was not the case.
In firefox their is no error.

While debugging I noticed that the main file mentioned in the data-main of the script tag is being called twice.

```
<script data-main="/ui/main.js" src="/ui/libs/require.js"></script>
```

Updating chrome to the latest version also didn't help.

One more clue that this might be a chrome update issue is while using one other app [Productive](https://producteev.com) I realised that its also made using backbone and require and in the console its throwing the same error

```
Uncaught Error: Backbone.history has already been started
```

Due to double calling of the main file the app is initialized twice and all the events are being triggered twice because of duplicate Views.

I'm not sure how to solve this. How can I avoid starting my app twice in case the main file is called multiple times. What can be a better approach to handle this kind of situation.

I'm using

1. Chrome (Version 44.0.2403.157 (64-bit)) on Mac OSX 10.10.4
2. require.js 2.1.18
3. Backbone.js 1.2.1

[EDIT] Adding sample : http://vipul261.github.io/test.html

you can check the main file named main.js

Main file:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
        requirejs([
            'domReady!'
        ], function (document, App) {
            alert('Hello');
        });
}());
```

Comment: You are using data-main correctly so there is something else at play here that we can't see without more code/a demo with the issue. `appHome-en_US.js` is not being called twice in ProductiveEv

Comment: I added the sample link of a test html file which has a main.js file attached as data-main..
Once more observation, The issue is not reproducible in incognito mode.

Comment: I wonder if something is wrong with your cache because this is working for me and not in incognito in Chrome 44. P.S. you don't need that domReady plugin since the script is below the other stuff in your body

Comment: After clearing cache also its not happening.. Tried on different machines, its happening for some and not for others.. Let me try on Chrome Canary

Comment: In Chrome canary things are working just fine. I think something is messed up in my Chrome. Every site using require is calling the data-main file twice for me. I tried removing extensions also but still its not solving the issue. Is their any other browser setting/parameter which affect require?